# MONACAのパーミッション　マイクの録音等を消したい

Tags: monaca

MONACAで作ったアプリのパーミッションで
Read Phone State
Modify Audio Setting
Record Audio
等を消したいのですが、できません。

MONACAのヘルプをみるとAndroidManifest.xmlで設定できるようなのですが、

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

しか見当たらないのです。弄れないようになったのでしょうか？

Mdeiaプラグインを使用したら上記のパーミッションが強制的に追加されちゃうんですかね？
不必要なパーミッションを要求しているので、ダウンロード数にも影響しちゃいます。こまったこまった。